# 写真のアスペクト比に関してのエラーについて

Tags: swift, xcode

UIimageでの写真のアスペクト比を最適化するために下のコードを書きました。

```
func resize(image: UIImage, width: Double) -> UIImage {

    // オリジナル画像のサイズからアスペクト比を計算
    let aspectScale = image.size.height / image.size.width

    // widthからアスペクト比を元にリサイズ後のサイズを取得
    let resizedSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width * Double(aspectScale))

    // リサイズ後のUIImageを生成して返却
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(resizedSize)
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: resizedSize.width, height: resizedSize.height))
    let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return resizedImage!
}
```

しかし、このようなエラーが出てしまい最適化されませんでした。

```
errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}
```

このエラーはどういう意味なのでしょうか、またどうすれば最適化されるようになるのでしょうか。
教えて頂きますよう宜しくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/143839

Comment: 「アスペクト比を最適化」と言うのが何をしたいのかよくわかりません。あなたのコードは単にwidth基準で画像をリサイズしているだけのように見えます。どんな結果を期待しているのかとどんな結果になってしまうのかを「最適化されませんでした」と言うよくわからない言葉を使わずに説明してみてください。